# VSCode C++ Intellisense Squiggles

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense

VSCode is randomly placing squiggles lines under my C++ code. Peak definitions and everything works for the underlined code, the code also compiles, builds, and runs fine. I also don't see the squiggles in Visual Studio 2013 nor QtCreator.

I have tried making changes to my `c_cpp_properties.json` file. I also used the intellisenseEngine to `Tag Parser` which does remove the squiggles, but then the coloring everything is wrong (i.e. `std::shared_ptr<>` is half white and half green). I assume I need to including something that I am missing here. Here is the current state of `c_cpp_properties.json`:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "x86-Debug",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools",
            "compilerPath": "C:/Program Files (x86)/VC/bin/amd64_x86/cl.exe",
            "cppStandard": "c++11"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Here are the squiggles that I am seeing. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmUEK.png)

Comment: It is a bit slow, so sometimes, closing and opening files make those squiggles go away. I have heard `clangd` is better, so you may wanna try that.

Comment: I've tried restarting my PC and VS Code several times as well as running CMake again and deleting the files and pulling down source again.

Comment: This is also legacy code, so I don't want to change the compiler to `clangd`.